# Can I use .submit as a function?

Tags: jquery, submit

I would like to show a div when the enter key or submit(/button) is used.
I tried:

```
$("#inputfield").submit( function () {
$("#div").show();
});
```

It doesn't work and I don't understand why. I googled for this but I didn't find a proper solution. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure all your `input` fields are wrapped inside of a `form` tag. Pressing enter, or submitting a form via the submit button doesnt trigger the `submit` event on the input that had focus when you pressed enter, or on the submit button, but rather on the `form` element. So you need to check for the `submit` event on your `form` element.

Also, showing a div on form submit wont be much help because the default action is to then redirect, so you need to prevent the default action by doing `return false;`. If you want to stay on the same page and show a div, yet at the same time still submit the form data, you cn do that via ajax using `$.post`

```
$("form").submit( function () {
    $("#div").show();
    $.post('some_url_to_submit_to.php',$(this).serialize(), function(data){
        //some action to take on success... but not necessary
    })
    return false; // to prevent the form from redirecting to a new page
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Input fields don't emit submit events. You need to wrap the input in a `form` and attach the submit event to that. Then it will work like you intend, as long as you remember to `return false` to prevent the form from actually submitting.

Comment: Hi, you are right. I tried this but it didn't work for my script: [http://jsfiddle.net/yomoore/eGF35/14/ It gives me an error: {"error": "Please use POST request"} I don't know how to proceed because I think this is PHP and I'm not familiar with PHP...

Comment: So the question is solved. I just want to say sorry for not mentioning the whole script because I assumed that would be better. But on second thought, I think It would have been better if I had elaborated more.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [`.submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form.

So you want to include `inputfield` in a form and bind the function like this:

```
$("#myForm").submit( ...
```